# Paging Support in Azure Function CosmosDB Input binding

Tags: binding, paging, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I'm trying to export data from CosmosDB to a different collection, by query.

I created a function with that query as CosmosDB binding parameter.

The function keeps timing out because the query results set is too large, and takes more than 5 minutes to retrieve.

Any suggestions how to run the export using Azure functions? Or should I take a different approach?

Comment: Functions are for event-based scenarios... Not the best option for batch operations.

Comment: Otherwise use a timertrigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to export data from CosmosDB to a different collection, by query.

According to your description, maybe you could try to use **DocumentDB Data Migration Tool** to achieve your goal. You could choose the Source Information and Target Information.And you could  add specific query statement by choosing **Enter Query** radio button. For more details, please read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data).

[image]

Comment: I didn't know of this tool. Thanks!
Still - I need a more complex transformation, the kind that requires code. I was hoping to avoid scaffolding the connections, batching, etc.

Comment: If you really want to export data by code, I suggest you could use Azure Data Factory. It could handle big data. For more details about Data Factory, you could read this article(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction).

Comment: @Amir you can use the Migration Tool and still [apply transformations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-transform-data-when-importing-to-azure-documentdb-2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the timeout of your function to a max of 10minutes in the Host file, but I agree with Mikhail, the trigger to Functions are intended for smaller workloads. You can create a durable function if you absolutely must have it in a function, but then you dont use the trigger but rather select from within the function.